# Does MobaXTerm's vim support netrw?

Tags: netrw

I'm trying to use my MobaXTerm vim to access a remote file using netrw as follows:

```
vim scp://my_username@my_server//path/file.txt
```

I have password-less login set up (through .ssh / rsa_id, etc.).

This works fine from my OS X machine running vim 7.3, but not from MobaXTerm vim (also 7.3).

Does MobaXTerm's vim support netrw?

Comment: Have you already read `:h netrw-ssh-hack`?

Comment: @Rich I have not -- actually, when I try to use `:help` at all in MobaXTerm vim, I get `E433: No tags file` :/

Comment: Ah. Here you go, then: https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_netrw.txt.html#netrw-ssh-hack I'd suggest trying to get it working *with* a password first, and then having a go at that. I guess check `scp` works in MobaXTerm outside of Vim, too.

Comment: @Rich Thanks for the link! I'll see what I can figure out. I also need to figure out why there isn't any `/usr/share/vim/doc` folder (where the help file would live). I should add: `scp` works fine from the MobaXTerm terminal.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to consider:

- what is your `g:netrw_scp_cmd`?
- you may need to give a full path to your system's scp

Comment: Hmm -- `g:netrw_scp_cmd` isn't set. Tried the full scp path (/bin/scp) but it simply tried to open a new file on my local system (as it did with scp alone)

Comment: The g:netrw_scp_cmd should be set after you've opened a netrw buffer, or if you've set it in your .vimrc.  Another thing: try :help netrw-debug and get a trace of what's actually happening.